# Why do i need at least two sockets to handle http connections?

Tags: freepascal

I found description of [simple web server at free pascal documentation](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Networking).
Example code uses two sockets: listenerSocket and connectionSocket. Why? I thought it should be enough one.

```
ListenerSocket := TTCPBlockSocket.Create;
ConnectionSocket := TTCPBlockSocket.Create;

ListenerSocket.CreateSocket;
ListenerSocket.setLinger(true,10);
ListenerSocket.bind('0.0.0.0','1500');
ListenerSocket.listen;

repeat
  if ListenerSocket.canread(1000) then
  begin
    ConnectionSocket.Socket := ListenerSocket.accept;
    AttendConnection(ConnectionSocket);
    ConnectionSocket.CloseSocket;
  end;
until false;

ListenerSocket.Free;
ConnectionSocket.Free;
```

Comment: Counter question : what would happen if you only used one socket and a second user tried to connect ? How should the server react and provide him a channel for communication ?

Comment: Client should wait in a kind of queue.. right? That is the reason?

Comment: But what will happen if 3 users will try connect in one time, one will be being served, another in queue, connection of third one will be rejected?

Comment: There is no queue, he simply will be denied access. Because of this one of the sockets is kind of a "reception" and then assigns a "hotel room" and waits for new customers afterwards